# Not Counting the number of input's and textarea's with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, count, keyup

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this script.  I'm trying to get the script to work first, and secondly, I need the numbers to count up.

The script works in demo: http://jsbin.com/ayalav/3/edit#javascript,html,live

But I can't get it to work on my webpage:  http://www.41q.org/admin/data/test.php

Thanks.

Comment: the links can die and may not be relevant in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap your JavaScript with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// your JavaScript goes here

});
```

Comment: What was I thinking... Thank u